# Using two cameras at a same time in Android Things

Tags: android, android-studio, android-things

I am in a situation where I need to use two cameras at a same time.

I have been looking up in internet for Camera2 api examples. Although not successful in developing my own camera app the way I want for android phone, I found some examples which open the camera.

Now I have a situation. I would like to know if I can access two cameras simultaneously in Android Things Odroid N2+ board. This is because I am working on the app that needs to open two cameras and display at the same time. For processing the image, I am planning to use OpenCV library.

Is this possible in Android/Odroid ?

Comment: 1) [Android Things was shutdown to new projects in 2021](https://developer.android.com/things) so you are on your own for support for that particular version of Android. 2) How are you connecting cameras to the board? If with USB Camera then unless [External Camera support](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras) is preconfigured you'll have to add in your own UVC library to get it to work. Also realize that official [concurrent camera support started with Android 11](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/concurrent-streaming)

Comment: 1) In Android Studio, there is option for Android Things, so could you elaborate when you say it was shutdown.
2) I am connecting my camera using USB. The camera is plug and play. It has been used by my team in Raspberry Pi. Its specification is elp-usb30w02m-l36.
3) Odroid N2+ runs on Android pie 9.0 so that means this cannot run two cameras.

Comment: Check my link, Android Things was a program for maker/ODM for using Android in their products for specific supported boards (RPi4 & NXP). Perhaps you are using a custom Android ROM using similar APIs, so would fall under "embedded Android". If the board manufacturer provided the ROM, questions about support should be directed there.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend to use UVC Library to access two camera. Android Things is not fit to this problem. I think this example help you. https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera